# Is there any way of getting CRX content without using OSGI

Tags: angularjs, osgi, aem, jcr, crx

Is there any way to get CRX content without using OSGI service?
Am looking for an use case to implement a top navigation for a website which is required to read page names and its properties via javascript framework like angular JS.

Comment: Here TopNav will be the component. If you are using sightly then use-api can help. If its in JSP the custom tags can perform the logic.

Comment: Thanks Vivek, but i am looking for a solution that can be achieved if any without any java calls and pure Angular JS connectivity to retrieve CRX content.

Comment: javascript use-api can be helpful, if you are avoiding java.

Answer (score 1):

You could get it as JSON or XML, make a server call to path with extension XML or JSON. JSON allows you depth based selectors to go down the tree hierarchy not sure if its same with XML.
`/my/page/path.xml` or `/my/page/path.<depth>.json`, you can get the hostname and port details from the request URI to make the complete URL for the data call.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use the following JSON API's provided by sling to accomplish your task of getting page names and its properties.

Firstly to crawl all the pages under a given path, you need to use the .pages.json selector. For example to get all child pages of /content/company/en_US, perform a JSON GET on

```
HTTP GET <Host>/content/company/en_US.pages.json
```

Next for each path returned by the above GET call, you need to grab the _jcr_content.json of the page

(E.g.)

```
HTTP GET <Host>/content/company/en_US/home/_jcr_content.json
```

The above JSON call should provide you all the page properties of this particular page.

Please Note: The above method is generic and can be applied to any JCR Path hosted in Sling/AEM. Also typically you cannot get this level of JCR access in a publisher environment due to security rules that might prevent JCR crawling. Hope this helps